# Why can't I mutate a slice via iterator mutable reference

Tags: rust

I'm trying to understand iterators and mutability. I have the following code that is supposed to basically copy one slice into another.

```
fn equate<T>(in_slice: &[T], out_slice: &mut [T]){
    for (ref i, ref mut o) in in_slice.iter().zip(out_slice.iter()){
        *o = *i;
    }
}
```

The code compiles, but when I test it, the out_slice parameter is unchanged.

```
let slice_test_in = [1i, 2i, 3i];
let mut slice_test_out = [0i, 0i, 0i];
equate(slice_test_in, slice_test_out);
```

slice_test_out is still [0,0,0] after the call. Why am I not mutating the second parameter?

Comment: You need to use `mut_iter()` instead of `iter()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems I was misunderstanding the 'ref' keyword in the destructuring. It was adding a level of indirection, instead of removing one like I thought. That, combined with the mut_iter() suggestion by @Athiwat, solved the problem.

```
fn equate<T: Clone>(in_slice: &[T], out_slice: &mut [T]){
    for (i, o) in in_slice.iter().zip(out_slice.mut_iter()){
        *o = i.clone();
    }
}
```